# How to generate test.yml file using python?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, devops

I need to generate a test.yml file using python.

for example: my python code supposed to create test.yml file and add the below ansible data to it.

the ansible data is as below:

-
name: Testing

host: localhost

vars:

-VM : windows

-name: testvm

-Ports:

-P2

can somebody help me here how to generate test.yml file with the ansible data mentioned above in the test.yml file.

Comment: Hi. This is not a "wrtie my code for me" site. I suggest your read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) paying particular to the [mcve](/help/mcve) section. You can then [edit](/posts/67366711/edit) your question with an honest attempt to fulfill your above requirement describing the errors you get and the problem you can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is quite basic, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    f=open("test.yml","w+")

    f.write('- name: Testing\n')
    f.write('  host: localhost\n')
    f.write('  vars:\n')
    f.write('    -VM : windows\n')
    f.write('    -name: testvm\n')
    f.write('    -Ports: -P2\n')

    f.close()

if __name__== "__main__":
main()
```